# Refresh only a part of webpanel in Genexus every (e.g.) 10 seconds

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, genexus, partial-page-refresh

I have a basic webpanel with a notifications icon. I want to refresh every x seconds this icon checking if unreaded notifications exist in DB.

How can I do it? I couldn't make work web notifications in Genexus.

How can I do it with jquery/AJAX or a kind of this?

Thanks!

Comment: Can you put your code in the question?

Answer (score 1):

You can create a web component with your logic and then refresh it every 'x' seconds.

1. Create web component 'wc_x'.
2. Change 'wc_x'Refresh timeout/Lapse property.

   - This property works with milliseconds, meaning 1 second = 1000 milliseconds.
   - https://www.genexus.com/en/global/news/read-news/work-panels-property-refresh-timeout
3. Edit the web form adding a table and putting your image inside.
4. Edit the Start Event and put your logic.
5. Call your new 'wc_x' in the web panel you want to see the image.